# What directory do I need to put my python packages in after downloading them from Anaconda Cloud?

Tags: python, installation, directory

I am downloading spacy, tensorflow, keras, etc.. from the anaconda cloud and then going to install them offline using conda install tensorflow - - offline.  What directory do I need to cd into in order for this to work?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can find answer here:

[Anaconda pip offline installation including dependencies (tensorflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43183361/anaconda-pip-offline-installation-including-dependencies-tensorflow)

Have nice day!